# Uploading Video in background in android

Tags: android, performance, memory-management, service

I am working on android application in which I have to upload video in background (max 200 mb) even if app got killed (if user's video upload is in progress). How to execute such long running task (probably if network problems occur). So that task should not get killed due to android memory or process priority constraints. As most tutorial on web using async-tasks. Any one have any good example or any library or utility which can handle this situation.

Comment: Try with ion library.@HardikMehta

Comment: the only thing you need is run your AsyncTask in the service (foreground service probably). So the tutorials are right - you can use AsyncTask. But to ensure it won't be killed by OS by timeout, you should use foreground service

Comment: @VladMatvienko can you provide any working example i am new to developement and have to complete this task

Comment: sorry, but making a working example of 2 features combined with each other will take a lot of time, and will make all your work instead of you. You can easily find hundreds of examples of foreground service, and file upload in the internet, and all you need is to combine them. If you really need urgently done something that you are not going to learn, you can hire a developer to do it instead of you for money.

Comment: @VladMatvienko if so,why i post question here insted at freelancer or other sites. although i have to complete task. if there is any utility i can also use it in future.

Answer (score 0):

I believe as per your requirement *Sticky* Service is best. The best part about *Sticky* Service is that it restart again when memory available if it was previously interrupted or stopped due to low memory.

Check this [link](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#START_STICKY) for Starting sticky services.